# Generate 0 entity in a run

Tags: simulation, distribution, exponential-distribution

Suppose to have an time interval ( from 0 to 3600000 that is one hour in milliseconds). I have to generate entity with average 3 and I utilise an Exponential Distribution. The average is (3600000/3) that is how I wanna sample the distribution. If in a particular run I obtain 0 entity create is wrong or can be correct result? Anyone can help me?

Comment: "I have to generate entity with average 3" - what do you mean by this?  Each entity has three pockets, eyes, or something else?  You want an average of three per millisecond, second, minute, or hour? You need to be more precise with your question.

Comment: I need tree entity in one hour in average...If I have 0 entity create it's error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an error to get zero.  With exponential interarrival times and a rate of 3 per hour, the number of occurrences in an hour has a Poisson distribution with λ=3. The probability of getting `n` outcomes is

> e<sup>-λ</sup>λ<sup>n</sup>/n!

which for n=0 is just under 0.05.  In other words, you would see a zero roughly one out of every 20 times.